# CSS on a page to center image inside the Pict Library SlideShow

Tags: master-page, css

The default alignment of the image inside the Picture library slide show is LEFT. In my attempt to place it right I was successful in changing the CSS (text-align:center) in the right place. My problem is that on the page there are 2 simple content query web part (title + description on the left and on the right of the slide show in a 3 column type of page) and they do happen to align in the center like the image inside the slide show.

Considering the line I change is the same for all 3, apparently, is there a way to center only the image inside the Picture slide show? Or to exclude from the alignment in center the 2 CQWP on the side?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to target the parent element by its `ID attribute` (it will look something like: `WebPartctl00_m_g_df2720b8_4c4c_463a_8394_30c22e458ff6`).

Unfortunately there are no classes applied to the slideshow webpart specifically.  I usually use auto margin on the image table like this:

```
#WebPartctl00_m_g_df2720b8_4c4c_463a_8394_30c22e458ff6 > table {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
```

Comment: You just embed that CSS in a CEWP on the page somewhere.